# What I need to install XNA Game Studio 4.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xna, windows-phone

I'm trying to download [XNA game Studio](http://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/), but at the moment I try to install it it says this:

[image]

Note: The Hyperlink sends me to a microsoft site to download VS2013 Express edition.

I'm on Windows 8.1 x64 with a full-component installation of Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XNA Game Studio has not been updated in many years. It requires [VS 2010 C# Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express) or VS 2010 Pro+. There are some hacks on the Internet about how people have gotten it to work with VS 2012 and VS 2013, but it's only officially supported for VS 2010.

Comment: Ok thanks, after reading your comment about hacks I just found this on CodePlex, which works perfect: http://mxa.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230, they also did another extension for VS2012 if someone is interested to.